# Make sure/check if property is selected in linq .Select() statement with unit test?

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing, iqueryable

Assume I have the following class:

```
public class Person
{
public string FirstName{get;set;}
public string LastName{get;set;}
public int Age{get;set;}
}
```

Assume I have this query:

```
var persons = someListOfPersons.Where(r => r.Age > 18)
                               .Select(m => new Person(){LastName = m.LastName});
```

As we can see above, I am selecting new `Person` objects with only the `LastName` property actually selected. Note that at this point this is still just an `IQueryable`.

How can I unit test this, to make sure that the `LastName` property has been included in the select statement?

Comment: You could have a UT where you create a dummy list of Person objects, where some of them are  over 18.  Then run the LINQ query and verify that in the dummy list, each Person object's last name matches that of a member in the IQueryable?

Comment: @LeslieDavies I guess I could do that, but I really want to check the Iqueryable itsself, like maybe with reflection or something.

Comment: Do you want to verify that the IQueryable is of Person class type?  Consider using the IQueryable.ElementType Property

Comment: Actually - just looked @ your code a little bit, this will not compile, consider: var persons = someListOfPersons.Where(r => r.Age > 18)
                                 .Select(m => new Person(){LastName = m.LastName});

Comment: @LeslieDavies yes ofcourse I guess i made a little mistake while simplyfing my problem :). I know of which type the IQueryable is, I just need to make sure that certain properties are included. I think I might be able to use the Expression property to check this though, will check it out. Thanks alot already

Comment: Oh ok, makes more sense :). Yep, just verify that (persons.ElementType.GetProperty("LastName") != null) or ( persons.Where(n => n.LastName == null).Count() == 0)

Comment: What is the point of this test? To test that MS's linq implementation is correct? It isn't really testing your code.

Comment: @kjbartel no, it is really to make sure that no-one removes a certain property from the select query

Answer (score 1):

I would focus on testing the actual behavior of the piece of code you are trying to test through its public contract. Testing implementation details like the type of returned objects, whether a getter was called, etc. ties your tests very close to the implementation, which means that any change in the code will require a change in the tests. This is something you want to minimize, or the cost of maintaining your unit tests will rise. You can find a nice article about testing behavior instead of implementation details [here](http://googletesting.blogspot.be/2013/08/testing-on-toilet-test-behavior-not.html).

Just as Leslie Davies mentions, I would also provide a dummy list of persons in my test and check whether the piece of code correctly returns only the last names of persons that are over 18.

Sidenote: If it's important that you only expose the last names through this piece of code, why not redesign the code so that it only returns names instead of incomplete Person objects? Returning Person objects that are only partly initialized may lead to confusion further down the road.

Comment: I only want to make sure that no one removes a property from the select clause.

Comment: You can verify this by checking that the result contains all the necessary properties instead of asserting that the code calls the getters in the Select statement. For example: Assert.AreEqual("Bob", person.FirstName); Assert.AreEqual(26, person.Age);

Comment: no, because that would mean I need to actually get the values, I am not intrested in those.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on why you're interested in the actual "getting" of the values instead of the values themselves? Is there any side-effect that's triggered when calling the getters of these properties? Or do the properties trigger a database call that you don't want to trigger in the test, but is necessary for production code?

Comment: I need to make sure that in the query, certain properties are not removed. Because the result of the query goes to other methods that NEED those properties. If they are passed into those methods as null (because they were not included in the select), I get alot of unwanted behaviour. And I cannot change the methods that handle the queries, I can only change the queries. So I need to make sure that in the future, we get notified when someone removes a property.

Comment: If you would only test that "the LastName property was called in the Select statement", you aren't really testing the externally visible behavior of your code under test. For example, the following snippet would pass that particular test but would still return Persons with uninitialized LastName properties: 
Select(m => { var foo = m.LastName; return new Person (){LastName=null}; })

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69477/discussion-between-prgmtc-and-thousand).